# Why did Daksha Prajapathi (father of Sati) hate Lord Shiva?

Tags: shiva, sati-goddess

Why did Daksha hate Shiva, though Shiva is his son-in-law and one of Trimurti?

Comment: Once after the birth of Goddess Sati,Lord Brahma had started to tell bad things about Vedas. Lord Shiva was very angry and he had cutted the fifth head of Lord Brahma. Prajapati Daksh the father of Sati was very angry on Shiva because he was the son of Lord Brahma. After that Daksh had started to hate Shiva.

Answer (score 14):

According to Shiva Purana, Daksha disliked Shiva due to the latter failing to properly respect him during a yagna.

However, there's more background to this as well.

Daksha, in addition to being a son of Brahma, was also a King, with a royal lifestyle; and being a King he wanted to use his daughters' marriages to increase his influence and power through marriage alliances with influential folks.

However, Sati, his youngest daughter had *always* been interested only in marrying Shiva. Daksha strongly disapproved of this as Shiva was an ascetic, and his followers consisted of ghosts, demons, ghouls and goblins. At this point in the tale, Daksha does not seem to be aware of Shiva being a "Supreme God".

Despite Daksha's disapproval, when Sati's swayamvara (a ceremony in which a bride can choose her own husband) was held, she chose Shiva and Daksha was powerless to stop the wedding. Leading to Daksha's hatred of the ascetic Shiva growing even stronger *because* he was now his son-in-law.

Answer (score 10):

As per Shrimad Bhagavatam, it is because Lord Shiva didn't show proper respect to Daksa Prjapati, at an occasion of Yajna.

> Dakṣa was adequately welcomed by the president of the great assembly,
>   Lord Brahmā. After offering Lord Brahmā respect, Dakṣa, by the order
>   of Brahmā, properly took his seat.  [SB -  4.2.7]
>
> Before taking his seat, however, Dakṣa was very much offended to see
>   Lord Śiva sitting and not showing him any respect. At that time, Dakṣa
>   became greatly angry, and, his eyes glowing, he began to speak very
>   strongly against Lord Śiva. [ SB - 4.2.8 ]

Being the Prajapati, he was of course a respectable man. So when every one else showed proper respect and good mannerism but not his own son in law Siva, he got angry on Him and hated Him. Anyway, he probably never liked Shiva because He was a *smashan* dweller. So that occasion made him furious and he poured his heart out:

> I had no desire to give my daughter to this person, who has broken all
>   rules of civility. Because of not observing the required rules and
>   regulations, he is impure, but I was obliged to hand over my daughter
>   to him just as one teaches the messages of the Vedas to a śūdra. [ SB
>   - 4.2.13 ]
>
> He lives in filthy places like cremation ground, and his companions
>   are the ghosts and demons. Naked like a madman, sometimes laughing and
>   sometimes crying, he smears crematorium ashes all over his body. He
>   does not bathe regularly, and he ornaments his body with a garland of
>   skulls and bones. Therefore only in name is he śiva, or auspicious;
>   actually, he is the most mad and inauspicious creature. Thus he is
>   very dear to crazy beings in the gross mode of ignorance, and he is
>   their leader. [ SB - 4.2.14, 15 ]

**Referece**:  [Shrimad Bhagavatam, Canto 4, Chapter 2](http://vedabase.com/en/sb/4/2)

Comment: Your explanation answers the question just partially. @Shisa has explained the main reason why Daksha began to hate Shiva.

Comment: @Dineshkumar yes, indeed it does. Actually the reason varies from *Puran* to *Puran* and I don't want to state something for which I don't have scriptural statements to back it up. In fact, I know another reason from Devi Bhagavata but did not mention it because I don't have the sanskrit text yet.